# Amortized analysis accounting method

Tags: algorithm, aggregate-functions, aggregate, amortized-analysis

I'm trying to find the amortized cost per operation in a sequence of n operations on a data structure in which the ith operation costs i if i is an exact power of 3, and 1 otherwise

can anyone explain me how to solve the problem

I found O(6), i dont know whether it is correct or wrong.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Please show us the code you want to calculate O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given `n`, there are `floor(log_3(n))` 'expensive' operations with cost `i`, the rest requiring `O(1)` each.

```
  O(1/n * (n - floor(log_3(n)) + sum_k=0..floor(log_3(n)) { 3^k }) )
= O(1/n * (n + (3^(floor(log_3(n))+1) - 1) / (3 - 1) ) )  // applying the formula for a finite sum of a geometric series
= O(1/n * (n + c * n) )
= O(1)
```

Note that the Big-Oh notation abstracts away from constant factors, so `O(6)` does not make much sense.

Comment: Can you please explain it to me, how to solve it using accounting method